# Custom mod_menu in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, menu, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I want to achieve something like this menu with two rows  http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#joomla17-templates.joomlart.com/ja_travel

To do so I need an html output similar to this examples

```
<ul class="joomla-nav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home<span>our home</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
 <ul class="joomla-nav">
 <li><a href="index.html"><span id="first">Home</span><span id="second">our home</span></a></li> 
</ul>
```

To do this html hack in joomla I need to modify default_component and default_url inside mod_menu but I don't know how.

Maybe I have to introduce some other field in the admin area of menu item.

What would be the solution?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I want to achieve something like this http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#joomla17-templates.joomlart.com/ja_travel if there is other solutions. Please give me!!

Comment: You should give us more information, what template are you using ? Also did you try to install a new menu module or not ?

Comment: I'm not using any template. I'm trying to do my template. I didn't try to install a new module because I would like to modify this module. It seems a little change.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a Mega Menu, there are several modules that create very similar menus. Joomlart's is built in to their framework so you could use the T3 Framework and build a custom template around it. then you would get exactly their menu. If you don't want to go through all the trouble you could try one of the 3rd party menu modules in the JED. I prefer this one -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/18101

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know how to modify the menu to achieve something like this, instead of using another menu module. It's a little modification so I think It can be possible without to much effort. Thanks!!

Comment: @dani : you should really try what Brent suggests, it will be much easier for you.

Comment: It's going to take a lot more than just that small HTML change. To achieve everything a good megamenu can do takes a custom module and an admin plugin for the menu manager at a minimum.